# How to move all files with specific extension from all subdirectories to their parent using CMD?

Tags: windows, file-io, cmd, directory, subdirectory

Folder `c:\folder1` contains `subfolder1`, `subfolder2`, etc..

These subdirectories hold `.pdf` and `.db` files.

How can all the `.pdf` files be moved to `c:\folder1` using the Windows command interpreter?

Comment: are you looking to do this with any particular programming language?

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned this. In MS-DOS using CMD.

Answer (score 39):

This worked for me:

#### In a `.bat` / `.cmd` file:

```
for /r "c:\source_directory\" %%x in (*.pdf) do move "%%x" "c:\target_directory\"
```

#### For direct input into a Command Prompt window (not PowerShell):

```
for /r "c:\source_directory\" %x in (*.pdf) do move "%x" "c:\target_directory\"
```

This command will copy recursively all `*.pdf` files from the source (and all of its subdirectories) to the target directory.

To exclude files in subdirectories omit the `/r` switch.

Hope it helps.

Comment: %x  is enough, %%x  is for a batch file

Comment: I think `for /r "b:\" %x in (*.mp3) do copy "%x" "c:\temp\cdrw"` works but don't know if it handles subfolders.

Comment: Is there a way to automatically overwrite/keep all duplicate named files instead of needing to respond back to every “yes/no/all” dialogue box

Comment: @Thunder_Ruler Answering with `a` (for "All") will overwrite all, however I don't know the option to *not* overwrite all.

Answer (score 8):

There is another way to do this in Windows Explorer (GUI, not command prompt):

- Navigate to the top-level directory
- In the search box in the top-right, type *.pdf and hit search
- Select all the files and drag them to the top-level folder
- Respond to any prompts about overwriting files

Comment: Good idea for small amounts of files. I'm trying it with 100,000 files and this method does freeze up things.

Comment: This worked great for a few hundred files from ~10 directories. I think this is particularly useful when you have a lot of locations, even with a small # of files.

Answer (score 7):

The outer for loop lists the sub-directories in the working directory, the inner for loop lists the sub-directories to move to the destination path:

```
for /d %f in (*.*) do for /d %e in (%f\*.*) do move "%e" DestinationPath
```

This works best if `DestinationPath` is not a subfolder of the working directory, as it will try to move `DestinationPath` into itself.

To confirm the command before running it wholesale, start out just echoing the final move commands like so:

```
for /d %f in (*.*) do for /d %e in (%f\*.*) do echo move "%e" DestinationPath
```

and copy/paste one of the results to run it and confirm it worked the way you expected. Then remove the echo and get moving.

Comment: This doesn't work if the subdirectories have spaces in their names

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there's a wildcard that will work on subfolders, so you want to use a loop to go through each subfolder and move *.pdf;

`FOR /R [your root folder path] %%G IN (*.pdf) DO move %%G [new path]`

The command after DO is inherently in its own quotes. If you anticipate spaces in your source or destination, use double quotes to encapsulate them, e.g.:

`FOR /R "source folder with spaces" %%G IN (*.pdf) DO move "%%G" "dest path with spaces"`

NOTE the quotes around %%G, these are required for the move command to resolve the path.

**EDIT: In response to the accepted answer,
From command prompts on Windows XP and Windows 7, respectively:

[image: command prompts]

This shows that a wildcard does not work in paths, only for files in a single directory (e.g. C:\folder*.files). The command prompt does not operate recursively when it encounters a wildcard.

Comment: This will go through ALL SUBFOLDERS, by the way, not just the first branch.

Comment: From prompts on WinXP and Win7: (mispost, ignore this)

Comment: you are correct, the poster wants a recursive solution which I misread.

Comment: Thank you Eaglebird, I tried your solution and I got "%%G was unexpected at this time". I would have uploaded a screenshot but I do not know how to do this.

Comment: tried to upload the image in the question but that control does not seem to be working in IE 7.0

Comment: I was getting error until I changed it to single %G

Answer (score 4):

I know this is superlate, but just in case it helps anyone.

Used this to search all sub-folders for a .MKV file and move them to the current directory the batch file resides in.

```
FOR /D /r %%F in ("*") DO (
    pushd %CD%
    cd %%F
        FOR %%X in (*.mkv) DO (
            move "%%X" "%CD%"
        )
    popd
)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
MOVE "C:\FOLDER 1\PDF FILES\*.pdf" "C:\FOLDER 1"
MOVE "C:\FOLDER 1\DB FILES\*.db" "C:\FOLDER 1"
```

After the move command, you have the source folder followed by the destination where the files will be moved to. The * in front of each file extension is a wildcard function that will select all of the specified filetype existing within that directory.

Also, if you can create a .bat file with these commands if you want to. To do this, paste your commands into notepad and save it as **.bat** instead of **.txt**

Then, you can double-click the file and it will execute the commands within the file each time you do. This is useful if you have any repetitive tasks that require this.

Answer (score 3):

Robocopy did wonders for me:

```
 robocopy c:\cache c:\cache-2012 ?????-2012*.hash /S /MOV
```

I used it to move all files with certain mask out of `c:\cache` and its numerous subdirectories.

Comment: you say 'move all files' but you ment `copy` right?

Comment: `/MOV` deletes the source after the copy

Answer (score 2):

Just taking a wild stab in the dark here, but if I remember correctly DOS can handle globs and the equivalent of `mv` is `MOVE`, so:

`MOVE C:\FOLDER1\*\*.PDF C:\FOLDER1\`

Comment: I tried `copy B:\*\*.* C:\temp\cdrw\ ` and got this error: `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo on

for /r "F:\All_drawings\newdrg\" %%x in (*.tiff) do move "%%x" "F:\Alldrawings"

pause
```

{moves all files from the `newdrg` folder and its "sub-folders" to the target folder `Alldrawings`, this command is for batch file operation for command line use single "%" in both the places}.

Answer (score 1):

To copy all text files to a folder and preserve directory structure:

xcopy *.txt /s D:Folder

Answer (score 0):

Open CMD at location `c:/folder1`

Run the following command:

```
mv ./subfolder1/*.pdf .
mv ./subfolder2/*.pdf .
```

Where `./subfolder1/*.pdf` selects all(*) pdf files in `./subfolder1/`

and

mv command moves all of them to the relative path `.`, which is the current directory `c:/folder1`

In place of relative paths (like `./subfolder1/`, `./subfolder2/` & `.`) you can also type full or absolute paths like `c:/folder1/subfolder1/`, `c:/folder1/subfolder2/` & `c:/folder1/`