# Batch script for moving files in different folders within a directory

Tags: batch-file, move

What i need is for the script to sweep the folders within a folder and pick up certain files and move them all to one destination folder.

```
MOVE C:\Users\AAA\Movies\**\*.mkv C:\Users\AAA\Move
```

**= scan through folders and move all mkv files is what I wanted.

I'm new to batch scripting and i was hoping the * would scan through the folders, but i guess it isn't that easy. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a wildcard for subfolders, so you'll need to use a loop. This question has answers that will help:
http://stackoverflow.com/q/4357233

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... and move them all to one destination folder ...

Try and adapt as needed

```
FORFILES /P "c:\Users\AAA\Movies" /S /M *.mkv /C "cmd /c move @path C:\Users\AAA\Move"
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly. i should be able to figure out the rest since i have a base now.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a  plain batch method - it will prompt on any filename collisions.

```
@echo off
for /r "C:\Users\AAA\Movies\" %%a in (*.mkv) do move /-y "%%a" "C:\Users\AAA\Move"
```